# Custom ordering on elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm executing a simple query which returns items matched by companyId.

In addition to only showing clients matching a specific company I also want records matching a certain location to appear at the top.So if somehow I pass through **pseudo** sort:"location=Johannesburg" it would return the data below and items which match the specific location would appear on top, followed by items with other locations.

**Data:**

```
{
  "clientId" : 1,
  "clientName" : "Name1",
  "companyId" : 8,
  "location" : "Cape Town"
},
{
  "clientId" : 2,
  "clientName" : "Name2",
  "companyId" : 8,
  "location" : "Johannesburg"
}
```

**Query:**

```
 {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "companyId": "8"
        }
      },
      "size": 10,
      "_source": {
        "includes": [
          "firstName",
          "companyId",
          "location"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Is something like this possible in elastic and if so what is the name of this concept?(I'm not sure what to even Google for to solve this problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in different ways.
Simplest (if go only with text matching) is use `bool` query with  `should` statement.

> The bool query takes a more-matches-is-better approach, so the score from each matching must or should clause will be added together to provide the final _score for each document. [Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Example:

```
{"query":
   "bool": {
     "must": [
        "match": {
          "companyId": "8"
        }
      ],
     "should": [
        "match": {
          "location": "Johannesburg"
         }
      ]
     }
   }
}
```

More complex solution is to store GEO points in location, and use [Distance feature query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-distance-feature-query.html) as example.